# Request Tracker (RT) REST API Error with Content

Tags: php, python, rest, httprequest, rt

I have tried posting the HTTP request multiple ways (both using PHP and Python) and I keep getting this error

```
string(341) "Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at /opt/rt4/share/html/REST/1.0/dhandler line 189.

Stack:
  [/opt/rt4/share/html/REST/1.0/dhandler:189]
  [/opt/rt4/share/html/REST/1.0/autohandler:54]
  [/opt/rt4/sbin/../lib/RT/Interface/Web.pm:634]
  [/opt/rt4/sbin/../lib/RT/Interface/Web.pm:334]
  [/opt/rt4/share/html/autohandler:53]
```

I tried to follow the [RT REST Guide](https://rt-wiki.bestpractical.com/wiki/REST) but I cant seem to install the HttpRequest they are using and I cant find the source code for it online.

Does anyone have any advice?

Here is my python code:

```
import cookielib
import urllib
import urllib2

# creates a cookie for the rtserver with the credentials given at initialization.
# define your credentials here

# here is the RequestTracker URI we try to access
uri = 'http://ip:port/REST/1.0/ticket/1/edit?user=username&pass=password'

# trying login on rt server
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
subdata = {'Subject': 'Test2', "Status":"open"}
data = {'content':subdata}
ldata = urllib.urlencode(data)
login = urllib2.Request(uri, ldata)
print(login.get_full_url())
try:
   response = urllib2.urlopen(login)
   print response.read()

except urllib2.URLError:
   # could not connect to server
   print "Not able to login"
```

And here is my php:

```
<?php
require('HttpRequest.php');
$username = 'username';
$password = 'password';
//set POST variables
$url = "http://ip:port/REST/1.0/ticket/1/edit?user=$username&pass=$password";
$fields = array("content"=>"Subject=Test2\nStatus=open\n");

$request = new HttpRequest('post', $url, $fields);
print($request->toString());
$request->doRequest();
?>
```

With the HttpRequest coming from [here](https://github.com/hay/httprequest/blob/master/class-http-request.php)

Comment: Did you solve problem?